# Tennis scores and right-to-left languages

Tags: localization

If a user has a right-to-left language set, do they expect that tennis scores would show the columns of sets flipped horizontally?

Comment: Do you mean `{first}{second}{third}` vs. `{third}{second}{third}` or `{players} {sets}` vs. `{sets} {players}` or `{game} {sets}` vs. `{sets} {game}`?

Answer (score 2):

Difficult question for a primarily L-R community. However, Tennis is an international sport and the scorelines should be standardized.

But if in doubt use small text labels to accompany the score.

Edit: Here you can see how it looks in real life in China from a quick google search.

[image]

Comment: +1 I think the use of numbers to indicate each set helps to resolve the ambiguity, and the scoring for each game compared to the sets are different so it is still easy enough to understand. I wonder if there are other examples from different countries in the world.

Comment: I'm certain there are many different examples and I'd bet that they'll ,almost all of them, use the same format.